# #2006 Cannot log into Mysql Server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

I am using a remote server to connect to my database. I was just working on my project and making sqls via php last night. When I woke up this morning and continued working, I tried to log in to the phpmyadmin over my browser for my remote server and got an error. When I set the remote server's ip address to the ip address in my machine's phpmyadmin config.inc.php file, I get the error #2006 Cannot log in to the MySQL server. I can continue to make sqls through my application however and log into Mysql through the terminal. It is only the phpmyadmin that is not working. Ive searched around but have not found any answers that have worked, nor have i found any situations that were similar to mine. I have tried upgrading Mysql but to no avail. I am not sure of what the error means or what caused the sudden problem.

I would also like to add that the I am using Google Cloud SQL and I have an unpaid balance for the month of August. Could Goolge have disconnected my phpmyadmin service? If that is the case, why can I still use my app smoothly with no interference and make sqls? If this is not the case, what could be the possible causes of this problem and where should I look to begin fixing? Error from phpmyadmin

Comment: If you can still connect from your application then it should work from `PHPMyAdmin` too. Maybe the IP from where you connect to `PHPMyAdmin` has changed? verify your authorized networks to connect to your Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: @JuanEnriqueMuñozZolotoochin My IP address changed and I needed to add it to the Access Control of the Cloud SQL instance. Thanks!